# app pool identity lightswitch isn't getting the logged on user

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a Lightswitch 3-tier web deployment and I'm stuck on the auth piece.  I've played with IIS and tried every config I can think of, but after I publish to the web, it always shows the app pool identity as the user in the top/right side of the browser.  The only way I can get the ID to "pass through" is to enable impersonation which I know isn't correct.  Even with impersonation enabled, the Administration tab doesn't show with the ID I assigned as the administrator after the initial publish.

Have you seen this?  I've tried this on multiple deployments, re-read the guides, re-read the LightSwitch book auth chapter, still to no avail.

Also, I find it curious that when I drop this code in a test.aspx  it shows that my ID is indeed getting passed:

`<%= User.Identity.Name %>`

But when I put this in, it shows the app pool ID:

`<%= Environment.UserName %>`

It's like Lightswitch is reading the Environment.Username (which will always be the app pool) instead of the user being passed by IWA.

What do you think is going on here?  I've relegated to NTLM at this point to make it "easy" (abandoning Kerberos for now) and it still doesn't work.

I have a great app that I'm ready to deploy, but I need to get security setup for it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I had earlier tested the website by simply copying the release from my visual studio project folder to the web server.  I decided to wipe the whole folder and publish "from scratch" and what do you know...it worked.

This is obviously my first experience with web development so just a noob mistake.  I'm still curious what was in the config that was over-riding what I was telling IIS to do, but for now I'm off an running.

You can close this issue.